# Problema de perfomance ao retornar json com rabl após consulta com activerecord

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Estou com problemas para ajustar a performance ao retornar json após uma consulta ao banco de dados.

Tentei várias coisas, e não estou conseguindo deixar mais rápido.

Alguém pode me dar uma força com isso ?

Essa é a consulta no controller
[image: controller]

Método no model
[image: model work]

Rabl
[image: show rabl]

Comment: Olá prefira postar seu código em texto ao invés de copiar e colar um print do mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Como recomendou o Carvalho cole o seu código em textos. Ficará muito mais simples te ajudar e você receberá mais fácil e rápido a ajuda se fizer da maneira correta.

### https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Sobre o seu código. Umas das coisas que estou reparando é que você está usando o SQL para varrer a tabela inteira e depois fazer o tratamento disso. Tente minimizar os esforços em banco em no array.

Vamos lá, trocaria esses métodos por isso

```
def students
  works_students.where.not(student: nil)
end
```

#### se você tiver usando esse mesmo conceito de students nos outros models com certeza o seu problema de perfomance estará ai. No entanto, se for somente esse, então provavelmente existe mais itens a ser analisado.

```
def program_id
  Qrcode.find_by(code: self.teacher_qrcode).try(:program_id)
end
```

Eu não sei quanto ao resto. Teria que analisar melhor essa tua implementação.

Nao sei melhor criar uma associação de `has_one :qrcode` no `model` teacher?

Tendo uma associação você poderia acessar diretamente o código pelo controlador assim:

```
work.teacher.qrcode.program_id
```